# Alfresco massive delete

Tags: alfresco, cmis

I'm trying to massive delete documents on alfresco.
I've tried this operation with a CMIS delete action for each file.
I tested it in my test environment (alf 3.4.7 Enterprise on Windows Server 2008R2 with about 5M documents) and it work valid but in my production environment (alf 3.4.7 Enterprise on rhel 5.5 with about 7M of documents) it doesn't work and corrupt lucene indexes.

Are there other way to delete a lot of docs in alfresco?
Thanks

Comment: Quite a few! What are you actual requirements?

Comment: I need to delete thousand documents from alfresco. I have a table in my db with the dbid and CMIS-object id of this documents.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a `org.alfresco.repo.batch.BatchProcessor, org.alfresco.repo.batch.BatchProcessor.BatchProcessWorker & org.alfresco.repo.batch.BatchProcessWorkProvider` to split your work into several parallel transasction.

If you don't want to archive your nodes, you can also speed up the process by adding cm:temporary aspect to every node before you delete it.